# libcurl - CURLOPT_MIMEPOST vs CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: c, http, curl, libcurl

Tell me please, what is the main difference between options CURLOPT_MIMEPOST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ?

What can be done with a CURLOPT_MIMEPOST - that cannot be done with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Sends exactly the bytes you specify in the body of the HTTP request. With a default Content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. libcurl will not add or encode the data in any way for you.

With the curl command line tool, you do this with `-d`.

### CURLOPT_MIMEPOST

Makes libcurl send a "multipart formpost". That is a data stream using a format that allows the sender to send multiple "parts" of data to the server, each part being properly separated and identified. Each part has a name, content and its own set of headers. When an HTTP client "uploads a file", this is almost always done using multipart formposts.

Multipart formpost is structured data in the request body and this option helps you produce and send that format. An application *can* also produce that format by themselves should they prefer that and provide it with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` or even using the callback `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION`.

With the curl command line tool, you do this with `-F`.

### See Also

https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl-http/upload

Comment: Thank you, that is, the  CURLOPT_MIMEPOSTis like a special case of a CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ? And I can use the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to implement the CURLOPT_MIMEPOSTis myself ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Let me expand my answer a little to make that clearer.